# Finding the inverse of an Integral Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms

I'm working with the following integral transform -

$\tilde{f}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,\frac{f(x)}{x + i y}$

What would be the inverse of a such an integral transformation?

Comment: OP's integral transform  (v1) is essentially the [Hilbert transform on the imaginary line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), whereas the usual Hilbert transform $H$ is defined on the real line.